# Gauss' Law Proof for a cube

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Some days back I learnt the proof of Gauss' Law by this method. ([Proof](http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/electricity/electricity/electrostatics/gauss_theorem.htm))
My teacher did it in this way using a sphere.

I got to thinking whether it can be proved using a cube instead of a sphere. I wrote some expressions, but I ran into trouble with the integration, as $r$ is not constant. Also, I thought I encountered double integrals.

Is it possible to derive the expression from $\phi = E.\Delta S$ for a cube? (In Cartesian coordinate system)
I assume that there is only a point charge inside a cube (may be assumed to be at the centre), and I want to find the flux through the cube) and want to derive the expression $\phi = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$

Comment: Also, please have a diagram in which your charge distribution is clear and show us how do you want to approach it? It really depends on your setting.

Comment: The "Proof" in the link you provided does not seem convincing to me.  It appears to assume that the charge is located at a point at the center of the sphere but then claims that the result is true if the charge is located anywhere inside the sphere.  This is indeed true, but I don't see this "proof" as adequate.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem with the proof given to me. In my textbook, it is proved for the specific case of the sphere, and is generalized just like that. I want to know if I can prove it in a similar manner, and using concepts which I know. (I'm in grade 11)

Comment: Which method? Can you add something into the question so that people don't have to click the link to see which method you're talking about? It doesn't have to be the whole proof.

Comment: well there are proofs for any enclosed surface, so...may be that is where you start. Isotropy of the problem should be of some help.

Comment: If you want, you can check Griffiths' Introduction on Eletrodynamics - in the first couple of chapters, they go over some concepts on vector calculus which are very useful in electromagnetism and they also show the calculation you're speaking of

Answer (score 1):

You want to derive Gauss's law from Coulomb's law.

If you have a charge $q$ placed at the centre, having coordinates $\mathbf{x}_c$, of a sphere, it produces a field$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c\|^3}$$at any point of the space of coordinates $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, according to Coulomb's law. I use $\varepsilon_0$ as a more common notation for what your link calls $\hat{I}_0$. The integral is often more succintly expressed as $$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}$$where $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c$. Therefore, for any sphere enclosing $q$ at its centre, the surface integral representing the flux is $$\Phi=\oint_{\Sigma}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=\frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}$$where $\mathbf{n}_e$ is the external normal unit vector to the surface $\Sigma$, in this case of the sphere. If $q$ is placed outside the region of space $E$ enclosed by the surface $\partial E$, which is assumed to satisfy the assumptions of [Gauss's divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), that theorem allows us to see that $$\oint_{\partial E}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e \,d\sigma=\int_E\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}\,dV=\int_E \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\nabla\cdot\left[\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c\|^3}\right]dx_1dx_2dx_3$$and, by calculating $\nabla\cdot\left[\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_c\|^3}\right]$, you see that, being the divergence $0$ for any $\mathbf{x}$ where it is defined, the integral also is $0$.

Now, if $q$ is enclosed in a surface $\partial V$ which may well be that of a cube, you can chose a sphere $B$, whose surface we call $\partial B$, so small that it is contained within the space $V$ enclosed by the surface $\partial V$. The flux through $\partial B$ is, as you know, $\oint_{\partial B}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e d\sigma=q/\varepsilon_0$. The flux through the surface of the region $V\setminus B$ is $$\oint_{\partial (V\setminus B)}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=\int_{V\setminus B}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}\,dV=0$$ as seen before by using the divergence theorem. You know that the flux through a surface "from the inside" is opposite to the flux "from the outside", since the external normal vector $\mathbf{n}_e$ change its sign by changing the orientation, which means that the flux though the surface $\partial (V\setminus B)$ enclosing $V\setminus B$ (the cube minus the sphere, in your case) is $$\oint_{\partial (V\setminus B)}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=0=\oint_{\partial V}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma-\oint_{\partial B}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma$$i.e. $$\oint_{\partial V}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=\oint_{\partial B}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=\frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}.$$If the charges $q_1,\ldots, q_n$ are more than one, the additivity of the surface integrals leads to $$\oint_{\partial V}\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{n}_e\, d\sigma=\sum_{q_i \text{ enclosed}}\frac{q_i}{\varepsilon_0}=\frac{Q_{\text{enclosed}}}{\varepsilon_0}$$which, as you see, is valid for any physical surface and not only a cube or sphere. I hope this helps.